# Laravel Dynamic Sidebar

Tags: php

I'm an asp.net developer but Laravel took my attention very well. I'm trying to build a blog with version 5. There are two siderbars the left is for articles and the right sidebar is for Categories,Lastest comments etc.

I can fetch the data from database and show articles but I couldn't find a way to show right sidebar.

I visited http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers. and tried to understand it however it didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an HTML/CSS issue: First design the layout that you want in your view, statically. Then you can split the layout into pieces (header, left sidebar, right sidebar, content, etc) and add them to the various views and layouts as needed. Then, substitute the dynamic data as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.

```
        View::composer('recent', function ($view)
        {
            $articles = DB::table('store')->get();
            $view->with('articles', $articles);
        });

        View::composer('news', function ($view)
        {
            $news = DB::table('news')->get();
            $view->with('news', $news);
        });
```

Use it wherever you want as a partial just like the below

```
@include("recent")
@include("news")
```